# C++ Mixins of 2 functional types

Tags: c++, mixins

I'm trying to write code that is effectively:

```
template <typename... Mixins>
class Checker : public Mixins... {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Checker(Args&&... args) : Mixins(std::forward<Args>(args))... { }

    bool check(void) {
        bool tests = true;
        // TODO: for each Mixins that has Mixin::check
        {
            tests = tests && Mixin::check();
        }

        if (!tests) {
            // TODO: for each Mixin that has Mixin::handle
            {
                Mixin::handle()
            }
        }

        return tests
    }    
};
```

I just don't know how to do the loops over just those Mixins satisfying the member conditions specified.  I've tried various solutions for iteration and for enable_if type semantics but nothing seems to compile.

**Additional**

So, what I've tried so far visa vi for-each base recursion and SFINAE function elimination is the following, which doesn't compile:

```
template <typename C, typename... Mx>
struct do_checks;

template <typename C>
struct do_checks<C> {
    static bool check(C *) {
        return true;
    }
};


template <typename C, typename E, typename... Mx>
struct do_checks<C, E, Mx...> {
    struct general_ { };
    struct special_ : general_ { };
    template <typename> struct int_ { typedef int type; };

    template <typename F, typename int_<decltype(F::check)>::type = 0>
    static bool check(C *ptr, special_) {
        if (!ptr->F::check()) {
            return false;
        }
        return do_checks<C, Mx...>::check(ptr);
    }
    template <typename F>
    static bool check(C *ptr, general_) {
        return do_checks<C, Mx...>::check(ptr);
    }
};
```

Where F should be E.  I don't know how to tell the compiler to compile the first "check" if the int_ has a type and the second if it doesn't.

Comment: What do you expect `Mixin` exactly to be? I can't spot any valid declaration for this in your code. Could it be you are confusing dynamic and static code evaluation?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I think what OP is trying to do is to call the `check()` method on each base class

Comment: @BrianBi ... which wouldn't ever work this way of course!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, but I thought it was clear the OP knew the code was wrong, but was just trying to convey the idea of what they want to do

Comment: Guys, @Brian is right, I want to call check for any base class that has that method, but not for any base class that doesn't so I don't have to have a lot of no-op methods for classes which don't have anything to check.  And yes, the TODOs are what I'm trying to figure out.  How do I write the code, filling in TODOs, to achieve what's described?

Comment: It's a question of there's one way to do the for-each recursion and another SFINAE technique for only calling E::check if E has a method check, but how do I combine these two techniques, if that's even the right approach?

Comment: @TimeHorse, wouldn't it be easier to just derive all the mixin classes from a base that defines trivial `check` and `handle` member functions? The compiler will probably optimize out all the redundant calls anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Brian .  I would like to know if it's possible though, but yes, simple "bool check() { return true; } is a nice backup plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a trait named `has_check` which returns true for a type which has a static `check()` method.

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class T, class = decltype(T::check())>
    std::true_type has_check_impl(void*);

    template<class T>
    std::false_type has_check_impl(...);
}

template<class T>
struct has_check : decltype(detail::has_check_impl<T>(nullptr)) { };
```

Then you can use it as the predicate to `std::enable_if` to enable/disable the overload if it has the method:

```
private:
    template<class T, class...>
    using first = T;

    template<class T = void,
             class = 
             first<T,
                   typename std::enable_if<has_check<Mixins>::value, T>::type...>>
    static void foo(void*)
    {
        auto x{ (0, Mixins::check(), 0)... };
        (void)x;
    }

    static void foo(...)
    {
        auto x{ (0, Mixins::handle(), 0)... };
        (void)x;
    }

public:
    static void check() {
        foo(nullptr);
    }
```

Comment: I think @TimeHorse actually wanted to run `handle` on *all* mixins, if any *one* of the `check`s failed

Comment: It's going to take me a while to refactor my code to follow the suggested paradigm but I do plan to try it and will happily award points if it works.  Just probably won't get to it until Monday.  Sorry.  :(

Comment: @TimeHorse No worries. Glad I could help anyway.

Comment: Thanks again for your patience.  It seems GCC isn't compiling decltype properly as I know GCC's support for it is still flagging.  The compiler chokes when I try to get the value constexpr from has_check<Mixins>.  But I see you've stripped the type of true_type or false_type when you derive has_check, both of which do have code for the value constexpr in GCC 4.8 and 4.7 so declexpr is the only thing I can guess is wrong.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, I stripped away the static as I need each Mixin to have the this pointer to its POD structure.

Comment: @TimeHorse What exactly is the error being shown? I ran this on GCC and it worked perfectly.

Comment: test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Checker<Mixin1, Mixin2>’:
    test.cpp:157:60:   required from here
    test.cpp:112:10: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘has_check<Mixin1>’
         void do_check(int)
              ^
And the same error for Mixin2.

Comment: @TimeHorse I'll have to run the code again. I'll get back to you when I figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @TimeHorse [Try this code please.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf5ce4a34062fb36)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing any code there, it's having trouble loading a couple files.

Comment: @TimeHorse Sorry, that site seems to be buggy today. [Try this one](http://ideone.com/Ld9dbd).

Comment: Okay, I've marked this as solution as it's pretty close.  I tried to remove static though as each Mixin has state so needs *this so I personally can't use it.  But I think it's good for others to see if they don't need their mixins to have state.

Comment: @TimeHorse Sorry but did this answer not help? How was it not answering exactly what you asked? 0_o

Comment: The original code for checking isn't static.  I tried to remove static and it doesn't compile (Checker<A, B>().check(); to construct an object rather than the static call).  I like your solution though so I want others to find it, but I actually needed a non-static solution.  I've moved onto another problem though, in terms of unpacking templates in a constructor, so I just think we'll leave it at that.